# PHP PDOStatement::fetchAll and grouping by key

Tags: php, pdo

There is a comment on php.org at [fetchAll page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

> You might find yourself wanting to use **`FETCH_GROUP`** and **`FETCH_ASSOC`** at
>   the same time, to get your table's primary key as the array key:

```
// $stmt is some query like "SELECT rowid, username, comment" 
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
// It does work, but not as you might expect:  
$results = array(  
  1234 => array(0 => array('username' => 'abc', 'comment' => '[...]')),  
  1235 => array(0 => array('username' => 'def', 'comment' => '[...]')), );
```

> but you can at least strip the useless numbered array out easily:

```
$results = array_map('reset', $results);
```

The code functions as expected and everything is accomplished with just line:

```
array_map('reset', $results);
```

After reading documentation array_map and reset function I don't really understand how the result is produced when both are combined in a single line.

Is it a safe solution? Would you recommend this kind of one-line or is it a side effect and should not be used, i.e. should I write a plain old loop to produce the same result?

Single line solution combining two standard functions is a very attractive solution to me. I just want to make sure there are no surprises.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22063422/870505) is the best answer IMO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is that `reset` in this very case is equal (suggest we are iterating through $results in `array_map`) to a `$results[$i][0]`. `reset`, besides internal pointer rewind,  returns the first element of the passed array, as simple as that.

As a side note I would suggest achieve this behavior with `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` implementing [ArrayAccess Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is safe. `array_map()` replaces an array member with callback function's result and `reset()` returns first member of array.
So,

```
array(0 => array('username' => 'abc', 'comment' => '[...]'))
```

is replaced with

```
array('username' => 'abc', 'comment' => '[...]')
```

as `reset()` returns this very line out of the former one.

But honestly, this is a kind of problem which never existed to me.
I don't understand what is so attractive in the idea of making one-liners using API functions only, producing whatever mind-breaking statements to abide one rule - "no user-defined functions at any cost".
I can make whatever function of my own, and it will be *shorter than any of these code twists* when called, yet have *plain and readable syntax in body*, without scratching your head both at writing and reading, without asking yourself a question "is it safe?".

So, a real one-liners would be my [safe and convenient database access library's](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql/blob/master/safemysql.class.php) `getInd` family functions (which allows *any* field as a key, not primary index only):

```
$data = $db->getInd("id", "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category=?i", $cat);
$dic  = $db->getIndCol("name", "SELECT name, id FROM cities");
```

you may notice that these are real one-liners, doing all the dirty and repetitive job inside, including query execution, parameter binding and stuff.