# set array keys on array initialization (pdo fetch_class)

Tags: php, sql, pdo, resultset

I'm working on a project, and part of that project requires that I convert some of my sql results into an array of class objects.

for convenience sake, i prefer to set my array keys to be the primary key of the sql row so i can access them quickly.

the way i'm doing it right now is to just remap every object to a new array and i set the key manually as $object->id. is there any way i can have pdo do this while fetching the initial array so i don't need to do what i'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do:

```
array_map(
    'reset', 
    $stmt->fetchAll(
        PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 
        'className'
    )
);
```

But that may not be much prettier than what you're doing now. See also [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#88699) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494085/php-pdostatementfetchall-and-grouping-by-key).

Or maybe something involving `PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR`?

Comment: pretty isn't that big a deal for me, i'm just trying to find a solution that will have the best performance.

i was thinking that copying the objects over to a new array would be a hit to my mem.

I like your solution, I'll probably try implementing it. Thanks :)

Comment: I like that solution, but it doesn't carry the primary key into the class. Assuming the class has a field for the PK, the value will be NULL.