# PDO set default fetch mode to FETCH_UNIQUE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I don't know why I cannot set the default fetch mode of PDO to FETCH_UNIQUE

Here is how I create the PDO object and make my request :

```
$PDO = new PDO($mysql,$login,$password);
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);

$prep = $PDO->prepare($selectQuery);
$prep->execute($params);
```

Then...

This is not working (it does not take into account the previous setAttribute()) :

```
$result = $prep->fetchAll();
```

This is working, but I don't want to have to write "PDO::FETH_UNIQUE" for every requests :

```
$result = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

What am I doing wrong ?
My goal is to get the result array indexed by the primary key of the selected table, exactly like on this thread : [Is there a way to fetch associative array grouped by the values of a specified column with PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361716/is-there-a-way-to-fetch-associative-array-grouped-by-the-values-of-a-specified-c/22063422#22063422)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

This does not work because, `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` is not a valid constant for `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE`. See here the valid fetch mode constants http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

It seems that there is no way to enable `PDO:FETCH_UNIQUE` using `$PDO->setAttribute()`. You should pass it explicitly in the call to `fetchAll()`.

Comment: The clarify: `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` sets the default fetch mode, not the default fetchAll mode. There's no way to set the default fetchAll mode. `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` is specific to `fetchAll()`.

Comment: Heck, it's a shame I'll have to write this for every request :(
Anyway, thanks for the info...

Comment: If you have to repeat your code you probably need to create a class to avoid that