# How to get the posts list and the associated tags with the smallest number of queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, angularjs

My tables are structured as follows:

**TAGS (more of a category):** id, tag name, description, slug

**POSTS:** id, title, url ...

**POSTSTAGS:** id, idPost, idTag

**USERS:** id, username, userSlug...

**VOTES:** id, idPost, idUser

Every post can have up to five tags and every user can vote only once. Currently, as the tags are not implemented yet, I retrieve my paginated result set with the following query:

```
SELECT p.*, u.username, u.userSlug, u.id as userId, 
exists (select 1 from votes v where v.idUser=$id AND p.userId=v.idUser AND p.url = v.url) as voted 
FROM posts p 
JOIN users u ON u.id=p.userId
ORDER BY p.created DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET :offset
```

The query gets ran via PDO and returned in JSON format to an angularjs `ng-repeat`. The `$id` is the logged in user's id. I use it in the `exists` subquery to gray out the vote buttons in my angular view (there is also a check on the server side). If someone clicks the username in the view, he will be taken to a detail page where all the user's posts are shown (`userSlug` to the rescue).

The next step is to include the tags in the result list and here I stuttered. Each post in the list must contain all the associated tags (tagName, description, slug) and each tag must take you to a details page where all the associated posts for that particular tag are shown.

The first solution that came to mind was to bruteforce my way through this after running the previously mentioned query:

```
foreach ($postsResult as &$post) {
    $sql ="SELECT t.* FROM tags t JOIN poststags pt ON t.id=pt.idTag WHERE pt.idPost=$post->id";
    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $tagsResult=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $post->tags = $tagsResult;
}
$response->write(json_encode($postsResult));
```

Done, easy peasy! Lot's of queries that will generate a huge amount of strain on the server. And we don't want to do that.

The second solution was to fire another query that fetches all tags associated with the postsResult(s) and then insert the corresponding tags in each post letting PHP do the dirty job.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT t.*, 
           pt.idPost 
      FROM tags t JOIN poststags pt ON t.id=pt.idTag 
     WHERE pt.idPost IN (array of post ids)
";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$tagsResult = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($postsResult as &$post) {
    $arr = array();

    foreach ($tagsResult as $tag) {
        if ($post->id==$tag->idPost) {
            $arr[]=$tag;
        }
    }

    $post->tags = $arr;
}
$response->write(json_encode($postsResult));
```

Is there any better or faster way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any better or faster way to do this?

If you index `$tagsResult` by `postId`, which you can do by using `FETCH_GROUP`, then you can remove the inner nested loop and grab all tags with a certain postId in constant time:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT pt.idPost, — select idPost first so it’s grouped by this col
           t.*
      FROM tags t JOIN poststags pt ON t.id=pt.idTag 
     WHERE pt.idPost IN (array of post ids)
";

$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();

$tagsResult = $smt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
//$tagsResult is now grouped by postId
//see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361716/is-there-a-way-to-fetch-associative-array-grouped-by-the-values-of-a-specified-c

foreach($postsResult as &$post) {

    if(isset($tagsResult[$post->id])) {
        $post->tags = $tagsResult[$post->id];
    }
    else {
        $post->tags = array();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your solution works with a small modification: the `idPost` cannot be unique as a post can have up to five tags. Removing `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` solved it. Thanks again.