# Mysql join get multiple rows at right

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables:

```
# products (id,name,value,time)

# product_data (id,product_id,field_name,field_value)
(1,1,color,red)
(2,1,size,big)
(3,1,whatever,value)
```

I want to make a query that takes field values from products table and also adds all product_data rows that have the same product id, like this:

```
$row = array(
  id => 1,
  name => Gloves,
  value => 15,
  color => red,
  size => big,
  ...
)
```

Maybe its not very good way to store all that data and I should store all fields in one table but since there will be a lot of different product types there always would be a lot of empty fields. The queries would be a lot simpler like that because I would have to be able to sort products by color for example (by values from `products_data`).

I have tried this for example but this only lists field names, not values:

```
SELECT *,
       group_concat(product_data.fname) AS afield
FROM product_data
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = product_data.pid
```

Comment: What query have you tried yet?

Comment: Could you please setup a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/)?

Comment: I updated my question. I also tried some other queries but none of them got me anywhere near what i wanted.

Comment: What about EAV model like magento does ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model

Comment: I only have experience with mysql so i want to stick with that. Maybe theres a better way to structure table that has to contain a lot of products with different parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037600/how-to-get-the-posts-list-and-the-associated-tags-with-the-smallest-number-of-qu/32038029#32038029) and question, as they are somewhat similar. It involves firing two queries and using PDO::FETCH_GROUP. You will get a `$product` row similar to this one:

```
$product = [
  'id' => 1,
  'name' => 'somename',
  ...
  'product_data' => [
    ['field_name'=> 'color', 'value'=> 'red'],
    ['field_name'=> 'size', 'value'=> 'XXL'],
    .
    .
    .
    ['field_name' => 'fabric', 'value' => 'cotton']
  ]
];
```

**Here is my version based on the hint above:**

```
$db = getConnection();
$sql_products = "SELECT * FROM products";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql_products);
$stmt->execute();
$products = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$productIds;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $productIds[]=$product->id; 
}
$productIds = implode(',',$productIds);
$sql_data = "SELECT product_id, field_name, field_value FROM product_data WHERE product_id IN ($productIds)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql_data);
$stmt->execute();
$products_data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_GROUP|\PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($products as &$product) {
    if(isset($products_data[$product->id])){
        $product->data = $products_data[$product->id];
    } else {
        // no data found, empty array
        $product->data = [];
    }
}
echo json_encode($products);
```

Comment: Thanks, ill try it out.

Comment: Interesting solution. Not seen that before and could be very useful. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this without the GROUP BY, building up the object in php. But would depend on where the result was needed, etc.

But it can be done using CONCAT_WS to push the name and value together before using GROUP_CONCAT. Just pick a separator between the name and the value that won't ever be used in the data.

```
SELECT *, group_concat(CONCAT_WS('~#~', product_data.fname, product_data.field_value)) as afield 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_data on products.id = product_data.pid
GROUP BY products.id
```

EDIT

One possible but nasty way to do this is to create a php serialized array from MySQL, then when you return the row you can just unserialize that field in php and access the values.

Down side is the code is messy, even ignoring field names or values that could contain a quote:-

```
SELECT *, CONCAT('a:',COUNT(product_data.product_id), ':{', 
            GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(';', CONCAT('s:', LENGTH(product_data.field_name), ':"', product_data.field_name, '";s:', LENGTH(product_data.field_value), ':"', product_data.field_value, '"')) SEPARATOR ';'), ';}') as afield 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_data on products.id = product_data.product_id
GROUP BY products.id
```

sql fiddle for this:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4751c/2

Comment: This gives me [afield] => color~#~15,size~#~100 not color and size fields seperately

Comment: You can just explode out the returned field in php to give you the names and values. If you want to get hideously complicated you can build up a php serialized array in the SQL instead of a simple delimited list