# How to use PDO::FETCH_GROUP to get a flat array?

Tags: php, pdo

I use `PDOStatement::fetchAll` with `FETCH_GROUP` and `FETCH_ASSOC` to get my table's primary key as the array key.

```php
$objects = $stmt_obj->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

This leads to the following result:

```
Array
(
    [56] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    ...
                )
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    ...
                )
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    ...
                )
        )

    [71] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    ...
                )
        )
)
```

What can I do to get rid of the useless numbered array and get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [56] => stdClass Object
        (
            ...
        )

    [39] => stdClass Object
        (
            ...

    [38] => stdClass Object
        (
            ...
        )

    [71] => stdClass Object
        (
            ...
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Heed the warning from @YourCommonSense [Is there a way to fetch associative array grouped by the values of a specified column with PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5361716/2943403).  Instead of using `FETCH_GROUP`, replace it with `FETCH_UNIQUE`, then you won't be bothered by the excess level in the payload.

Code: ([PHPize Demo](https://phpize.online/s/k4))

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
var_export($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_CLASS));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to map over the array. Add the `PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE` flag and the result will have each element as a single object, rather than an array of objects.

```
$objects = $stmt_obj->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_CLASS | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

See [this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php#122665) in the documentation.

Comment: Warning from YCS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48901316/2943403